# Передать с AngularJS на slim framework параметры запроса

Tags: php, angularjs, slim

Нужно передать параметры запроса, этих параметров может быть несколько (в зависимости сколько выбрал пользователь), там например нужно искать по такой-то стране, по такой то дате, по такому то формату и так  дальше, ну и в итоге вывести результат.
Проблема в том что не могу передать параметры с front-end к back-end..Использую AngularJS и slim framework.

Пример кода на php

```
$app->get('/items', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
   // $file = 'log.txt';
    $input = $request->getBody();
    //file_put_contents($file,$input);
    $sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT items.name, items.link, items.owner, items.date_start, items.date_end, items.description, format_file.format_name FROM items, format_file WHERE items.id_format_file = format_file.id AND format_file.format_name = "' .$input['format'] . '"';
    $rows = DB::fetchAll($sql);
    $response->getBody()->write(json_encode([
        'data' => $rows
    ], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));

    return $response;
});
```

и пример кода js

```
mainApp.controller('NewsViewController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.getPosts = function(){
        var paramSearch = {};
        paramSearch.country = $scope.country;
        paramSearch.format = $scope.format;
        var jsonParamSearch = [];
        jsonParamSearch[0] = 'country';
        jsonParamSearch[1] = 'format';
        var jsonParam = JSON.stringify(paramSearch, jsonParamSearch, "\t");
        console.log(jsonParam);
        $http.get('http://localhost:8088/api/rest.php/items', jsonParam).success(function(){
            console.log('done');
        });
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для передачи параметров get запросом, их нужно указывать через params:

`$http.get('myUrl', {params: {country:"myCountry", format:"myFormat"}})...`

Попробуйте так передавать параметры на сервер:

```
$scope.getPosts = function(){
    var paramSearch = {};
    paramSearch.country = "myCountry";
    paramSearch.format = "myFormat";

    $http.get('http://localhost:8088/api/rest.php/items', {params: paramSearch})
    .success(function(){
        console.log('done');
    });
};
```

В браузере нажмите f12 -> network и посмотрите какие данные передаются.

Comment: slim не может прочитать, это $input = $request->getBody(); возвращает пустоту, передача происходит, в консоле: /api/rest.php/items/?country=myCountry&format=myFormat

Comment: Сам php не знаю, но судя по документации попробуйте `$input = $request->getQueryParams();`, должно заработать.