# Передача Json c AngularJS на PHP (Slim framework)

Tags: php, javascript, json, angularjs, slim

Нужно передать JSON с ангуляра, вот набросок кода:

```
mainApp.controller('NewsViewController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.getPosts = function(){
        var paramSearch = '{"name": "wiki", "field": ["name", "owner", "description"]}';    

$http.get('http://localhost:8088/api/rest.php/items/', paramSearch)
                .success(function(res, status, headers, config){
                    console.log(res.data);
                });
        };
    });
```

Принимаю код в PHP использую Slim framework

```
    $app->get('/items/', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    //$file = 'log.txt';
    $input = $request->getQueryParams();
    //file_put_contents($file, $input) ;
    $sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT items.name, items.link, items.owner, items.date_start, items.date_end, items.description, format_file.format_name FROM items, format_file WHERE items.id_format_file = format_file.id';
   if (isset($input['name'])) {
            $sql = $sql . ' AND items.name LIKE "%' . $input['name'] . '%"';

    }
    $rows = DB::fetchAll($sql);
    $response->getBody()->write(json_encode([
        'data' => $rows
    ], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
    return $response;
});
```

Делаю так, то $request->getQueryParams() возвращает пустоту, я так понимаю он предназначен для обычных параметров в ссылке

Comment: Вы повторяете свой [вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/588440/218319), для отправки данных гет запросом указывайте их через `{params: "мои данные в виде json объекта"}`, как указано в ответе приведенного вопроса.

Comment: мне понадобилось передать JSON, я попробовал так как вы говорите, но оно не корректно передается, вот например исходный: '{"name": "wiki", "field": ["name", "owner", "description"]}' и от что передалось:{"wiki", "fineld": ["naame", "ownemr", "descreiption"]}": " .... я подумал что это для этого не предназначено, и решил спросить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для отправки параметров гет запросом с помощью AngularJS, параметры этого запроса нужно оборачивать в {params: 'тут данные в виде json объекта' }, должно выглядет так: `$http.get('myUrl', {params: "мои параметры"})...` пример:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    
            $scope.getPosts = function () {
                var paramSearch = {"name": "wiki", "field": ["name", "owner", "description"]};
    
                $http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/rest.php/items/', {params: paramSearch})
                        .success(function (res, status, headers, config) {
                            console.log(res.data);
                        });
            };
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <button ng-click = "getPosts()"> Нажми меня</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

получается запрос такого вида: http://localhost:8080/api/rest.php/items/?field=name&field=owner&field=description&name=wiki

В браузере нажмите f12 -> network и посмотрите какие данные передаются.

Comment: увидел свою ошибку, нужно было без кавычек в paramSearch, но в итоге всеровно ошибка: GET http://localhost:8080/api/rest.php/items/?field=name&field=owner&field=description&name=wiki net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: А свой объект поместили в `{params: "мои параметры"}`?

Comment: да, {params: paramSearch}

Comment: Проверьте путь, куда идет запрос, что бы он рабочий был. Поскольку это гет запрос, то отредактируйте его прямо в браузере в адресной строке и сделайте запрос.

Comment: да была ошибка в URL, но проблема в том что с "field": ["name", "owner", "description"] остается только description, то есть "name", "owner" пропадает...

Comment: Ладно, попробуйте у массива вызвать метод toString, т.е. `"field": ["name", "owner", "description"].toString() `, должны передаться все данные.

Comment: спасибо, за ответы, .toString() мне не подходит, так как потом будет тяжело вытащить значения, я сделал вот так: '{"name": "wiki", "field": {"name": "name", "owner":"owner", "description":"description"}};'...заменил квадратные скобки на фигурный и приписал параметр значения

Answer (score 1):

Используйте POST запрос.

```
$http.post('http://localhost:8088/api/rest.php/items/', data).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response); 
}, function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: возвращает вот такое "<br />
<b>Deprecated</b>:  Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the php://input stream instead. in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
{"data":[{"name":"Результат.."}]}"

Comment: выходить что данные возвращает, это объект data, а от как убрать это предупреждения

Answer (score 0):

Вы отправляете GET запрос, а нужно POST. Если хотите использовать GET то передавайте параметры в query string.

Пример: http://localhost:8088/api/rest.php/items/?foo=bar&foo2=bar2